# How to replace a part of string

Tags: sql-server

I want to update the substring between the two first successive `parameter`
I want to write a query which will do the same effect as the example below , `johnold` is just an example

```
a= 'parameterjohnoldparameter123parameter'
b='aaa'
```

result would be

```
a= 'parameteraaaparameter123parameter'
```

How can I do something like that ?

Comment: on what basis replace b ?wht should i look for ?explain.

Comment: Is there any text before the first `parameter` or will the first value always be found at position 10?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stuff it in there.

```
declare @a varchar(30)
declare @b varchar(30)

set @a = 'parameterjohnoldparameter123'
set @b = 'aaa'

select stuff(@a, 10, 7, @b)
-- or do a search for the second parameter string
select stuff(@a, 10, charindex('parameter', @a, 10) - 10, @b)
```

Comment: +1 Better than my answer, assuming the part to be replaced works on ordinal position and is fixed length rather than being a specific value.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for:

```
SET a = REPLACE(a, 'johnold', b)
```

But how do we know what the part of the string you want to replace in the first string is? I've just guessed based on your example.

Answer (score 0):

To change in a single table

```
 UPDATE `table_name`
 SET `field_name` = replace(same_field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text')
```

Answer (score 0):

From: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

```
REPLACE( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
```

example:

```
SELECT REPLACE('Hello World', 'Hello', 'Goodbye Cruel')
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using fixed length or searching parameters you can use:

```
declare @a varchar(max),@b varchar(max),@c varchar(max)

set @a = 'parameterjohnoldparameter123parameter' --original row
set @b = 'aaa' --value to insert
set @c = 'parameter' --value to insert after it

select stuff(@a, LEN(@c)+1, charindex(@c, @a, LEN(@c)+1) - LEN(@c)-1, @b)
```

Or even calculate LEN(@c) one time before select.

Comment: Because we don't know max length of each parameter: a,b,c. I used "max", but if author knows the real max value (for example, replaceable part is from some column varchar(100)), we can use exact value. I understand that "max" isn't good idea for performance.